# Exception from MySqlDataReader.Read() while there are huge number of records in C# Project

Tags: c#, mysql

Currently I am working on a C# project.
The purpose of the project is to read MySQL database records by executing select query.
To read the database records, I am using MySqlDataReader class and perform ExecuteReader() function.

Database connection and reading sample code.

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
            // process data here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But getting below exception from reader.Read() function if there are huge number of records (i.e. 20000 or more).

> ```
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
>   HResult=0x80004005
>   Message=Fatal error encountered during data read.
>   Source=MySql.Data
>   StackTrace:
>    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Read()
>
> Inner Exception 1:
> MySqlException: Reading from the stream has failed.
> ```

If there is anyone face the same, please share the solution. It will be highly appreciated.

Note: If there is same question available, please share the link.

Comment: Are you able to read less than 2K records? with the same function?

Comment: Please verify the Connection string, and also let us know the query you are executing

Comment: @Kaushik do you mean 2000 records? if so then yes...

Comment: @HamzaKhanzada the connection string is "server={0};uid={1};pwd={2};database={3};Connection Timeout=600;" 
The query is a simple select * from <table name>

Comment: The error comes when you try to read the first item from reader? Or it comes after few records? After how many records do you get the error?

Comment: If you comment out `// process data here` does the issue go away? That might tell us if the issue is some kind of timeout.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The error comes after several hundred records reading (not counted the exact number)

Comment: @gsmaker Default `TimeOut` for `MySqlCommand` is 30 seconds. I guessing, your code is crossing this Timeout while executing large number of records. Try increasing TimeOut and verify once.

Comment: As a countermeasure, I have changed the select SQL query to use range in limit option like below and error is not occurring.
SELECT * FROM <table-name> limit 0,2000
Meaning getting 2000 records each time and process.
Thanks all and @Kaushik

Comment: I had the exact same problem when reading over 50'000 rows. Setting the Command-Timeout to 3000 seconds solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely experiencing a timeout issue. If you know this query may take a long time to run, you can increase the timeout on this one `MySqlCommand`:

```cs
using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    command.CommandTimeout = 600; // in seconds, i.e., ten minutes
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the net timeout settings.

`MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("set net_write_timeout=99999; set net_read_timeout=99999", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: (Sorry for a silly question)
Does this net_write_timeout and net_read_timeout parameter will set to database permanently, or it will be reset once the SQL connection session ends?